# What's going on with Meta rep?

Tags: support, reputation, per-site-meta

I asked a question on meta SO for the first time since the split.

I received a couple of up votes (great), yet my rep hasn't changed.

Come to think of it, my rep appears to be my SO rep and my old Meta rep is no longer on SE Meta.  What happens when I'm upvoted on SO Meta?  I'm not really that bothered but some clarification would be nice.

Comment: See [Reputation of MSO will be reflected on SO?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250077)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is entirely covered in the [What's Meta help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) - click on Help > Meta:

[image]

Then you'll see:

[image]

Comment: To be fair, this was a very recent change.

Comment: Perhaps @Pëkka - To be fair, MSO still have the notice about the new MSO in [the top](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dKNmO.png).

Answer (score 11):

Meta Stack Overflow is now a regular per-site meta, and you don't get reputation from upvotes on per-site metas.

Answer (score 5):

Before the split, the rep you earned on Meta Stack Overflow was added separately to the stack and you got the rep and badges.

But since Stack Overflow has its own Meta site now, that site won't be add any sort of the reputation that you earn by any means.

Also, you must have noted that the Meta SO now has the same Reputation that you have on the SO site. Same everything and same privileges. You won't get any reputation increment by being a helpful user in the Meta site.

Comment: Badges are tracked differently between a site and its meta. Other than that, yes.

Comment: @ChrisForrence, thanks for that :-) I have edited it now..